# how to run Phone gap iOS app in background (minimized) when no internet connection found

Tags: ios, cordova

i am developing an ios phonegap app and currently when no network is found post the "no network found" alert a black screen stays in my app and the app remains open. I have seen with other apps where internet is required and it minimizes it in the background once you click OK on "no network found, try later" type of alerts.

Andriod allows it to exit the app on no network found, but Apple doesnt, so what is the solutions here to minimize the app & allow it to be seen in teh background by double clicking the home button on iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can not close/minimize an app on iOS, most app are kept in memory even if you go back to the home screen.

Only audio, location, accessory and VOIP apps are really allowed to keep running in the background. All other apps are just suspended when they are going to the background.
Until the device runs out of memory the app is kept in the memory.